AX88179a self assigning IP
My ax88179a interface is self-assigning its IP address. I do not know how to fix it, and know very little about network functioning. I know that my router, computer, and PTZ cameras are plugged into an 8-port network switch so I can control the cams via IP. I need a step-by-step walkthrough how to fix the issue with the interface. It worked fine for a long time, but I think it got messed up when I updated to Sonoma 14.5. Please help. I tried a new interface but it didn’t fix the issue.

Can you try the following: shutdown your Mac, restart your router, wait a minute and then restart the Mac.

If the interface is configured to obtain addresses via DHCP, then there must be a responsive DHCP server on the network it is connected to.
If the OS does not receive a response to the DHCP request, the OS will self-assign an APIPA address to the interface.
If there is no DHCP on the network, you can statically assign an IP to the interface.
